# Facebook Graph Api publishing to feed returns: "(#100) Param place must be a valid place tag ID"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am searching at Facebook Graph Api, using graph api explorer, for some place using the following endpoint:

> /search?type=place&q=centauro&fields=id,name,link

I am getting this as response:

```
 "data": [
    {
      "id": "492103517849553",
      "name": "Centauro",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Centauro-492103484516223/"
    },
    {
      "id": "313439499156253",
      "name": "Centauro",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Centauro-313439462489590/"
    },
    {
      "id": "175812113006221",
      "name": "Centauro",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Centauro-175812079672891/"
    },
    {
      "id": "1423220914594882",
      "name": "Centauro",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Centauro/1423220891261551"
    },...
```

When I try to publish using the field "id" returned:

> /me/feed

with fields:

> message: Testing
>
> place: 492103517849553

I get the following reponse:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Param place must be a valid place tag ID",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "DfEKOjZX8g+"
  }
}
```

But if I use de final number of the link:

> "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Centauro-492103484516223/"
>
> 492103484516223

And try again:

> /me/feed

with fields:

> message: Testing
>
> place: 492103484516223

It works perfectly.

So, is there a way to get te correct place id for publishing? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the “(#100) Param place must be a valid place tag ID” error, but got it to go away by providing a JSON string within the 'place' element.

So where the content of your request was this:

> place: 492103484516223

Format the place information like this instead:

> place: {"id": "492103484516223"}

Answer (score 0):

### Currently, this is how you can solve it.

```py
import requests 

IG_USER_ID = <YOUR INSTAGRAM USER ID>
USER_ACCESS = <YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN WITH VALID PERMISSIONS>
CONTAINER1_ID = <ID OF FIRST CONTAINER>
CONTAINER2_ID = <ID OF SECOND CONTAINER>

URL = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/{IG_USER_ID}/media?caption=Fruit%20candies&media_type=CAROUSEL&children={CONTAINER1_ID}%2C{CONTAINER2_ID}&access_token={USER_ACCESS}"

r = requests.post(URL)
```