# Facebook Graph API - Check-Ins Post on Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create posts like below-using graph API.

[image: Facebook Graph API - Page Post]

I am using  API version **v7.0** for searching for places and then using `{page-id}/feed` to create a post. I tried *sending a **place** as well as **coordinates*** in post request but nothing seems to work.

In facebook API docs, place field type is string but it is not working. so i found [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452394/facebook-graph-api-publishing-to-feed-returns-100-param-place-must-be-a-val) regarding that and send it as json instead of string. Error was gone but created post only contains message, no location or map in the facebook.

Thanks

[image: Facebook Graph API Explorer]

Comment: What you get from the places search endpoint, is not a Page object, but a PlaceInformation object. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search#limitations

Comment: Yes, I know. I am only using ID from places search API in {page-id}/feed API as you can see in 2nd image

Comment: _Which_ ID? The place ID? That is wrong, you need to use the ID of the page associated with the place.

Comment: Got it. But it requires business verification which I don't have

Comment: Plus, Search API deprecated in v8.0 and will be deprecated in other versions from November 2, 2020. Is there any other way I can search for a location or place?

Comment: No, not that I know of. If there was any replacement, then they would probably have anounced that by now, resp. mentioned it in the existing documentation.